# Highcharts: Get point value of Plotline intersecting with series line

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, linechart

I have more than one plotline in line-chart. This line is movable(user can drag) and I need to show the point values of Plotline intersecting with series line. I need to get x-axis & y-axis value of the point of intersection as shown below. [image]

I want the value of highlighted area of intersection (red & black section in plotline). Plotline section in code:

```
plotLines: [{
            id: '1',
            color: '#00F',
            width: 4,
            value: 100
        },
        {
            id: '2',
            color: '#002',
            width: 4,
            value: 200
        }]
```

Full working sample in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kk8322/syvs8qoh/)

Comment: Only what comes to my mind is that scenario. Get path of plotLine and calculate  y function (as in maths). Next step is loop over points to find two points, between serie line is printed. Having two lines, calculate if these elements crossing.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried the same today. I am little bit successful in that attempt. But problem is y-axis value. Y-Axis is rendered in "logarithmic" scale, so intersection point calculated is not mapped properly. Any suggestion on how to map calculated y-axis value to scaled (log) axis value ?

Comment: If someone is looking for this kind of behaviors then visit forum link - https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=44138&sid=64c6417fba5473990bb4feb3fb533713